# Where to insert relay for large power supply

Tags: power-supply, ac, relay, dc

I have a power supply I believe was originally used for LED lighting panels. It can output 24 V at a max of 7-8 A. I intend to use it to drive a solenoid valve by putting a 70 ohm resistor in series with the valve and power supply.

I also plan on controlling the circuit with a relay, would there be issues with placing the relay on the DC part of the circuit? Or is there a problem with suddenly shutting off current on a circuit that probably includes inductors as part of the conversion circuit?
Otherwise I would need to place it in the AC part of the circuit which would be significantly more dangerous.

Comment: Please draw a schematic of what you are proposing.

Comment: Why not use a MOSFET? Do you need the isolation provided by the relay?

Comment: danger depends on the specs of your components.  relay and solenoid specs needed to determine feasibility.  wattage of resistor is important too.

Comment: Why would you put a resistor in series with the power supply? That sounds very suspicious and unlikely to do what you expect.

Comment: What are the voltage and coil resistance of the solenoid? I'm guessing that it's 12V with a coil resistance of 70 ohms and you're using the 70 resistor to divide the 24 volts in half, is that correct? Worst case with 24V through 70 ohms is ~ 350mA, it shouldn't be hard to find a relay that will handle that.  You will probably want to have a flyback diode across the solenoid coil if you're switching it like this. The supply may need some minimum load as well, a resistor or even a light bulb across the output before the relay contacts, but that would depend on the supply.

Comment: You might want to look at this question on adding resistors in series with solenoids:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275927/resistor-in-series-with-solenoid-valve-for-voltage-reduction